# modelling status of an Order

Tags: java, status, modeling

What is the best way to model the `status` of an `Order`?Currently I am doing it the dirty way,by hardcoding like below

```
class Order{
   ...
   String orderStatus;
   ...

   public Order(){
     ...
     orderStatus = "pending";
   }
}
```

Later on when the status is changed to say `confirmed`,I would

```
myorder.setOrderStatus("confirmed");
```

But,I begin to smell it is not the right way..What should be the correct way of modelling it?Should I use Enumerations?..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using an Enum would be a lot better than using random strings yes.

I would look into the [State](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern) design pattern, otherwise I think you might well end up with lots of code that is conditional on the current state variable which is also pretty smelly.

Answer (score 1):

An enum and a state machine with well-defined transitions.

Answer (score 0):

enum is good for the situation that changes very infrequently.
But it will very be very convenient to change is you keep them in datebase.